# Can not set env variable in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some shared env. vars for some containers.
So I want to build ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL using these 2 shared vars..

```
version: "3.7"

x-environment: &commonEnvironment
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      <<: *commonEnvironment

    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - goboards-net

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo_express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      <<: *commonEnvironment
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD@mongo
    networks:
      - goboards-net
```

But while running **docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build -d**
I am getting

```
WARNING: The MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Nevertheless, mongo have these vars, but mongo-express does not. Cant understand why.

Comment: What is the result of `docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml config`? Has it been rendered correctly?

Comment: @Andromeda yeah

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `docker inspect mongo-express | jq '.[].Config.Env'` I bet you'll see that your first two environment variables are set **in the containers**.
Docker Compose does not however take your variables set in `&commonEnvironment` and use them later in the file.

When you write `$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, the **$** makes it a reference the variable from **Docker Compose's** environment. As they are not set you get the warning for the line `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL`

To actually build `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL` you need to set those in your shell like this:

```bash
export MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
export MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

or set use an env-file:

```bash
echo MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root > .env
echo MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root >> .env
```

When the variables are set you would use them in your docker-compose-file:

```yaml
x-environment: &commonEnvironment
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

There are [more ways to set environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) with docker compose.

Maybe a file called `prod.env` used like: `docker-compose --env-file=prod.env -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d` would fit your use case.

Use `docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml config` to make sure all variables are interpolated correctly.